# change CSS class content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have links that, on hover, will display "bar" after.

```
.link
{
   color:aqua;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: none;
}

.link:hover span {display:none;}
.link:hover::after {content: attr(data-content) 'bar';}
```

[image]

My objective is, on document load, to attach "foo" to in front of "bar" in the content. I have referred to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin) for help, but cannot seem to find a solution.  This did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
     $('.link').attr('data-content','foo');
 });
```

Any suggestions on what is going wrong would be highly appreciated.  How can I change the content of `.link` on document load?

Comment: what's in `data-content`? can you post the html, too?

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle with your question.  At face value, your jQuery doesn't appear to be the issue, I'm guessing the CSS is, or the relationship between how CSS reads the `attr` and load time.  This is clearly solveable, but may require a more jQuery-focused approach vs the CSS approach to reading the content.

Comment: Seems to work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6tt6k2L1/

Comment: nothing is in `data-content`, it is an attribute that is created in the jQuery function

Comment: is that what u asking for https://jsfiddle.net/mouner/4h96mcy3/

Comment: yes but it's not working for me

Comment: could u paste full page code in ur question